# Why does dropping a reference compile and work?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Hello");
    drop(&s);
    println!("{}", s); // prints `Hello`
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=83025d386d2efe50d6c9415cab3fabea)</sup>

Why does this code compile and work? More specifically, I don't understand the following:

1. Why I can use `s` in `println!` after I dropped it? Doesn't `drop` free the underlying resource making it unusable?
2. According to [the `Drop` trait docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/std/ops/trait.Drop.html), the function `drop` accepts a mutable reference, which doesn't make any sense to me - shouldn't it accept the value itself instead of a reference?
3. Let's assume it accepts a mutable reference — in the code above I pass an immutable reference - so why does it still work?

Comment: You are looking at 1.0.0 docs. They are valid, but they have probably been improved in the last 4 years.

Comment: You are looking at `Drop::drop` but calling [`drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html).

Comment: @Shepmaster I see, thanks - it creates a copy of a reference and then drops this copy - so basically nothing happens on `drop(&s)` line. It's not obvious that immutable references implement `Copy` by default. People say Rust is too explicit, but from what I see, sometimes it's not explicit _enough_ :)

Comment: well, you write `&` pretty explicit to me